# Edit robots.txt from admin panel in OpenCart

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

I want to edit my robots.txt file in OpenCart 2.* from admin panel. Does anybody know how to do it?

Is it a standard feature or I need to install any extensions?

List of modules or code examples will be perfectly.

Comment: Nobody will help?

Answer (score 1):

Hi OpenCart does not have robots.txt file by default. There is no setting in admin panel too.

However this is very simple, you can simply create robots.txt file in your website root directory. A brief example of syntax is given below.

Robots.txt is a text (not html) file you put on your site to tell search robots which pages you would like them not to visit.

It is important to clarify that robots.txt is not a way from preventing search engines from crawling your site (i.e. it is not a firewall, or a kind of password protection) and the fact that you put a robots.txt file is something like putting a note “Please, do not enter” on an unlocked door – e.g. you cannot prevent thieves from coming in but the good guys will not open to door and enter.

Block all web crawlers from all content

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Block a specific web crawler from a specific folder

```
User-agent: Googlebot
Disallow: /no-google/
```

Block a specific web crawler from a specific web page

```
User-agent: Googlebot
Disallow: /no-google/blocked-page.html
```

Sitemap Parameter

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
Sitemap: http://www.example.com/none-standard-location/sitemap.xml
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But it isn't what I wanted exactly. I wanted see a ready plugin. And you gave me an exampleof robots.txt for OpenCart. It is a useful information, but a lot of opencart's assemblies (ocStore, ocShop, for example) already contain this file. So, I don't need to make it manually. I wanted just a tool for editing robots.txt through admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write module that can edit file. So look on [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)